# How to query for full sets where multiple members contains different properties

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have two tables: `PERSON` and `VEHICLE`.  Each `VEHICLE` has an `OWNER_ID` FK back to `PERSON.ID`.  I want to find the `LICENSE_PLATE_NUMBER` of all vehicles owned by all people who own at least two cars painted different `COLOR`s.

So if Jack owns three cars, and one of them is a red car and the other two are blue, I want the query to return Jack's `ID` and the `LICENSE_PLATE_NUMBER` *for all three of his cars.*  But Fred, who owns two black cars, should not be in the result set.

Is there any way to express this in a single SQL query?

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward enough if you just break it down into steps.

```
CREATE TABLE people (pid int PRIMARY KEY, pname text);
CREATE TABLE vehicles (vid int, colour text, licence text, owner int REFERENCES people);

INSERT INTO people VALUES (1, 'Jack'), (2, 'Fred');
INSERT INTO vehicles VALUES (101, 'red', 'CAR101', 1), (102, 'blue', 'CAR102', 1), (103, 'blue', 'CAR103', 1), (201, 'black', 'CAR201', 2), (202, 'black', 'CAR202', 2);
```

OK - so people and vehicles with the values you described.

```
SELECT p.*, v.* FROM people p JOIN vehicles v ON  p.pid = v.owner;
 pid | pname | vid | colour | licence | owner 
-----+-------+-----+--------+---------+-------
   1 | Jack  | 101 | red    | CAR101  |     1
   1 | Jack  | 102 | blue   | CAR102  |     1
   1 | Jack  | 103 | blue   | CAR103  |     1
   2 | Fred  | 201 | black  | CAR201  |     2
   2 | Fred  | 202 | black  | CAR202  |     2
(5 rows)

SELECT
    p.*
  , COUNT(DISTINCT v.colour)        AS num_colours
  , ARRAY_AGG(licence ORDER BY vid) AS licences 
FROM people p 
JOIN vehicles v ON p.pid = v.owner
GROUP BY p.pid;

 pid | pname | num_colours |        licences        
-----+-------+-------------+------------------------
   1 | Jack  |           2 | {CAR101,CAR102,CAR103}
   2 | Fred  |           1 | {CAR201,CAR202}
(2 rows)


SELECT
    p.*
  , COUNT(DISTINCT v.colour)        AS num_colours
  , ARRAY_AGG(licence ORDER BY vid) AS licences 
FROM people p 
JOIN vehicles v ON p.pid = v.owner
GROUP BY p.pid
HAVING count(DISTINCT v.colour) > 1;

 pid | pname | num_colours |        licences        
-----+-------+-------------+------------------------
   1 | Jack  |           2 | {CAR101,CAR102,CAR103}
(1 row)
```